# Ruby LoadError cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, load

Im new in Ruby.

This is an output of terminal when i type "rails --version"

/home/juldou/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/juldou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rails-4.2.3/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /home/juldou/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in`'

Comment: Are you using a Ruby/Gem version manager, eg RVM?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install rails gem? if not, run "gem install rails" this is great resource that explains how to install ruby, rails and database.
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04